# Merge [tag:evaluation] and [tag:model-evaluations]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tags [evaluation](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/evaluation) and [model-evaluations](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/model-evaluations) seem synonymous. Let's merge them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Makes sense. They have similar descriptions as well:

```
updating post history, 329 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 308 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 293 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'evaluation': [evaluation] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 340
tag remapping of [model-evaluations] and [evaluation] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
9 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
91 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym evaluation -> model-evaluations was approved!
```